# GCP: Run kubectl exec on private cluster over proxy

Tags: proxy, google-kubernetes-engine, bastion

I have a private kubernetes cluster with private ip.
In order to access it i have set up a bastion host with squid proxy.
It looks like this:

```
My host -> bastion -> private cloud
```

Regular kubectl commands work throw proxy as expected:

```
$ HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 kubectl get pods 
No resources found.
```

The problem is when trying to ssh to a pod:

```
$ HTTPS_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080 kubectl exec -it "some-pod" -- /bin/bash
error: error sending request: Post https://<master-ip>/api/v1/namespaces/ns/pods/some-pod/exec?command=%2Fbin%2Fbash&container=xxx&container=xxx&stdin=true&stdout=true&tty=true: EOF
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Topic related with this other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548736/ssh-to-kubenetes-pod-using-bastion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is said in this other [Stackdriver post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548736/ssh-to-kubenetes-pod-using-bastion), the EXEC command use [SPDY2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY) so it cannot be implemented.

More details in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/58065)